# ¿Cómo obtener números consecutivos faltantes en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es obtener los numeros consecutivos faltantes,para este ejemplo sería los numeros: 2, 6,8,9
estoy tratando de realizar esta query:

```
SELECT
P1.numero FROM
documentos P1
LEFT JOIN
documentos P2
  ON P1.numero = P2.numero - 1
WHERE
P2.numero IS NULL
```

pero resulta que muestra los numeros 1, 5, 7,10. Es decir de donde comienza a faltar, pero lo que deseo, como dije antes es mostrar los numeros consecutivos faltantes.

Tambien he realizado la siguiente query:

```
SELECT a.numero+1 AS inicio, MIN(b.numero) - 1 AS fin
FROM   documentos AS a, documentos AS b
WHERE  a.numero < b.numero
GROUP  BY a.numero HAVING inicio < MIN(b.numero);
```

En donde me muestra dos columnas de donde empieza a faltar los números consecutivos, pero quiero que me liste todos los números consecutivos faltantes.

Alguna idea de como hacerlo? Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Estás solo usando MySQL o estás algún otro lenguaje para manejar los datos? PHP, JavaScript....

Comment: solo MySql, pero se entiende el objetivo?

Comment: mysql? o maria?

Comment: Disculpe, pero no se entiende bien? ya había puesto que es MySql, en el titulo, en el tag y en el comentario, no se cual es lo complicado de la pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjunto un ejemplo de como se podría realizar con un procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `ObtenerNumerosFaltantes`()
BEGIN

DECLARE maxNumero INT;
DECLARE minNumero INT;

SET maxNumero = (SELECT max(numero) from documentos);
-- SELECT concat('maxNumero es ', maxNumero);

SET minNumero = (SELECT min(numero) from documentos);
-- SELECT concat('minNumero es ', minNumero);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE NumerosTemp
(
    numeroTemp int
);


WHILE minNumero <= maxNumero
DO
    INSERT INTO NumerosTemp VALUES(minNumero);
    SET minNumero = minNumero + 1;
END WHILE;


SELECT 
    S.numeroTemp AS NumerosFaltantes
FROM
    NumerosTemp S
    LEFT JOIN documentos T ON
        S.numeroTemp = T.numero 
 WHERE T.id IS NULL;    

DROP TABLE NumerosTemp;

END
```

Comment: Excelente, era lo que justo responde a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En postgreSQL existe la función generated_series que puede servir para tu consulta

La query te quedaría algo como esto:

```
SELECT generate_series 
FROM generate_series(1, 9999)
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT d.id,cast_to_int(substring(d.numero from 7 for 5 ))::int numero FROM documentos d
) aux ON generate_series = aux.numero
WHERE aux.id is null
```

En MySQL podés consultar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql para generar la serie

Saludos!