# Encontrar GAPS de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Espero puedan ayudarme con este problema llevo horas intentando resolverlo pero no logro que funcione del todo.

Se busca identificar de forma automatizada estos huecos para que se puedan reutilizar esos números de ficha
cuando se vayan a agregar nuevos registros de fichas. Por ello, empleando solamente queries SQL de tipo
SELECT, habrá que dar respuesta a las siguientes preguntas:

1. ¿Qué Fichas_No están faltando en la tabla de fichas, en el rango del 1 al 100? R= 16 fichas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Ejemplo de como esta mi tabla de fichas] Ejemplo de como esta mi tabla de Ficha_No

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Esto es lo que me da pero es erroneo, porque faltan mas números.

Adjunto la sentencia:

```
SELECT f1.Ficha_No+1 FROM fichas AS f1
LEFT JOIN fichas AS f2
ON (f1.Ficha_No + 1 = f2.Ficha_No) WHERE f2.Ficha_No IS NULL AND f1.Ficha_No <= 100;
```

[image: Resultado deseado] Resultado deseado

Comment: ¿Cuál es el query que estás utilizando? Sería bueno que lo agregaras para que des más información y otros puedan ayudarte.

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar

Comment: Listo ya quedo agregada la sentencia que use

Comment: Entra aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118450/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-n%C3%BAmeros-consecutivos-faltantes-en-mysql

Comment: Hola, ya intente lo de ese link pero no me funciono. Pero gracias por la ayuda.