# Encontrar correlativos faltantes mysql

Tags: mysql

**Contexto**: Tengo una BBDD en mysql que procesa(envía y recibe) comprobantes cada minuto, hace poco me reportaron que la cantidad de comprobantes que envían no cuadra con la cantidad que reciben, esto es porque el servidor al cuál envió falla al devolver unos comprobantes, sin embargo todos los comprobantes tienen un correlativo de secuencia numérica, por lo que abrí una hoja de calculo, hice una función para identificar la secuencia faltante y empeche a jalar esa función, pero la información es tanta que es muy tedioso hacer esto y aquí viene mi consulta

**Pregunta**: ¿Cómo podría hacer la consulta de registros con correlativos faltantes en una BBDD mysql?

**Ejemplo**

```
Tabla de comprobantes
FECHA       OP  SERIE   CORRELATIVO
-----------------------------------
9/08/2021   0   B003    21776
9/08/2021   0   B003    21777
9/08/2021   0   B003    21778
9/08/2021   0   B003    21779        <------- faltante 
9/08/2021   0   B003    21781        <-------  21780
9/08/2021   0   B003    21782
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Sin definición de tablas, datos de prueba, salida esperada a partir de esos datos y consultas que has probado, es muy difícil ayudar sin adivinar. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: esta pregunta esta duplicada, favor ver [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118450/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-n%C3%BAmeros-consecutivos-faltantes-en-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con MySQL >= 8.014 puedes crear una vista con los correlativos posibles mediante una *Expresion Recursiva de Tabla Común*.
A partir de ahí obtienes los correlativos inexistentes haciendo outter join con comprobantes.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(i,max) AS(
  SELECT min(correlativo)
       , max(correlativo)
    FROM comprobantes
  UNION
  SELECT i+1, max
    FROM cte
    WHERE i< max
)
SELECT i correlativo
  FROM cte
    LEFT JOIN comprobantes
      ON correlativo = i
  WHERE correlativo is null
```